# Prevent an ASP .NET page having to poll a database for a change

Tags: sql, database

I have a ASP .NET web service that leverages a long lived connection from the client.

- The client connects in and waits for 15 minutes for a response.
- Just prior to 15 minutes, the ASP .NET Web Service responds with an OK.
- The client repeats this connection establishment.

During the 15 minutes, the Web Service checks for a change in a field value in a record in an SQL table.  If that value changes it then immediately sends a response to the client with ReadMessage.  This checking / polling of the database is done every 30 seconds.  This has several drawbacks:

1. it does not scale well.  It works well with 1 or 2 clients, but when you end up with 10,000 client connection that is a lot of polling on the database.
2. It leads to latency in processing as it may take up to 30 seconds for the client to be notified.

What I would like is to find a way of notifying the Web Service for the active http client that the record has been updated.

It should also be noted that each client connection to the web service has it's own specific record in the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [SqlDependency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency.aspx) is what you are looking for. Query Notifications allow applications to receive a notice when the results of a query have been changed

Comment: This looks like the perfect solution.  I see an example at:  http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/chatter.aspx.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered setting up some triggers in the db? If you are using SQL Server you can use SQL Server CLR integration.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254963%28v=VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: With some additional research it would appear that this will not solve the problem.  This will result in external code being executed.  The issue I have is that this code will not be able to communicate though with the existing thread in ASP.NET which is the web service.

Answer (score 0):

You could put a trigger on the table.  Disclaimer: I try to stay away from triggers because it's very easy to write one poorly and when it errors it's hard to debug.  However, I haven't ever written a CLR trigger and I imagine there's a little more safety in that since you have more control over error handling.

But even better would be to have whatever process is updating the table to begin with notify your webservice of the change if that's an option.

Comment: I could have the process that is updating the table call a webservice.  However, I'm not sure how the webservice can then notify the instance.

Comment: However, I'm not sure how the webservice can then notify the instance.  I guesss this becomes an inter process communication issue.

Comment: Why is it a problem to make the webservice notify the instance?  If my psychic abilities are working then I think the answer might lie in keeping a collection of the instances in a globally available place.  I don't know much about webservices though so sorry if that makes no sense :)

Comment: I.e. when an instance starts it would add some kind of reference to itself to a collection you can access from the process that gets notified of table changes.  Like I said though, I'm kind of guessing at what the issue is and what you can do with a webservice so if that doesn't help you might try asking this question specifically on SO.